# How to link a controller to a directive in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

**Lets say I have the following `HTML` structure:**

```
<div ng-app="testApp">
    <div ng-controller="controller1">
        {{controller1}}
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="controller2">
        {{controller2}}
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="controller3">
        {{controller3}}

        <test-directive></test-directive>
    </div>
</div>
```

Inside `ng-controller="controller3"` there is a custom directive.

**The directive is as followed:**

```
ang.directive("testDirective", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            console.log(scope);
        },
        template: "<h3>I return $scope.controller3</h3>"
    }
});
```

The `$scope` now holds the data from `ng-controller="controller3"`.
How can i link a **custom** controller to it? So instead the directive passes its *parent controller*, I want too pass for example *controller1* its data.

I have to be able to pass any controller to it, because the *directive* is depended on the data inside a given *controller*.

I cannot replace the `<test-directive>` inside the required controller

**Here a fiddle you can play with**

```js
var ang = angular.module('testApp', []);

ang.controller("controller1", controller1);
function controller1($scope) {
 $scope.controller1 = "controller1";
}

ang.controller("controller2", controller2);
function controller2($scope) {
 $scope.controller2 = "controller2";
}

ang.controller("controller3", controller3);
function controller3($scope) {
 $scope.controller3 = "controller3";
}

ang.directive("testDirective", function() {
 return {
  restrict: 'AE',
  link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
   console.log(scope);
  },
    template: "<h3>I return $scope.controller3</h3>"
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp">
 <div ng-controller="controller1">
  {{controller1}}
 </div>
 <div ng-controller="controller2">
  {{controller2}}
 </div>
 <div ng-controller="controller3">
  {{controller3}}
  
  <test-directive></test-directive>
 </div>
</div>
```

---

### Real case scenario:

I made a **pagination** directive. You can call the directive by placing `<ng-pagination></ng-pagination>` anywhere on the page.

The directive creates a pagination from a given dataset. The dataset however can hold anything. It doens't depend on values or whatever.

There is only one **requirement** for the directive. It looks inside the controller if it has a `$scope` called `$scope.result`. The `$scope.result` gets filled with data from an *API* call.

The pagination then recreates a `object` with *10* results per page.

The problem I have is: The `ng-controller` can be anywhere on the page also can the `<ng-pagination></ng-pagination>`.

**What i want to archieve is something like this:**
I assign an *data attribute* to the `[ng-pagination]`. Called: `data-controller`. You can then pass the controller name to it. The directive then has access to all the data inside that controller.

**It would then look like this:**
`<ng-pagination data-controller="controller1" show-next="true" ...></ng-pagination>`

---

### UPDATE

I found out that you can assign a controller by doing:

```
ang.directive("directive", function() {
    return {
        controller: "[CONTROLLER NAME]"
    }
});
```

I though, perhaps this is possible:

```
ang.directive("directive", function() {
    return {
        controller: "{{controller}}",
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            $scope.controller = "[CONTROLLER NAME]"
        }
    }
});
```

However, it gives me the error:

> **Error: ng:areq Bad Argument** 
>   Argument '{{controller}}' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: Take a look at [scope properties](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) - You need to access `$scope.$parent`

Comment: Thanks for the awnser. I cannot use `$parent`. Its not as simple as that. Because the `controller` can be anywhere on the page. Also, if you look the snippet you can see the `$parent` doens't hold any `controller` data. As far as i can see.

Comment: Oh, I thought they are nested. So you can't pass `controller1` from `controller3` because they have completely different scope, you could use `$rootScope` which I **don't recommend**, but you can use a factory - Let me know if [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers) helps, and I'll mak yours as duplicate

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the link to the question im familair with. But its not about sharing data between controllers or any kind. What i need is some `$scope` variables. For example: `$scope.data`. So what i want is, when you call the directive, you asign a `controller` to it, which has the `$scope.data`. The `directive` is depending on that variable. Is there no way i can do someting like `controller="controller1"`?

Comment: See updated question. Explained the real case scenario.

Comment: Since you need only $scope.data, can't you create a rootScope variable (or even better, a common controller) in which you handle the data you want, and then you create scope.data to pass to the directive itself?

Comment: As for `$rootScope`. I perhaps can play around with it. As far as i know, and as @AlonEitan stated, using `$rootScope` is not recommended. Regarding you question about a global controller which handles the data. I can't do that. There are 100+ controllers, to different API calls :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **I was playing with `controller` as seen in my update, and reading this [guide](https://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives-part-two/). I came up with below solution**

**So how can you pass any `controller` to a `directive`?**

- You first have to isolate the `scope` with `scope: {}`
- Set the controller property inside the directive with `controller: "@"`. You can now assign values to it with the next step
- Set the property `name: "controller"`. Ill explain how to use this below.

**I have been told `isolating` the scope is necessary, it does work without however.**

If you now place the `directive` you can now assign any controller to it by doing:

`<ng-pagination data-controller="[CONTROLLER NAME]>`

The name of the property `name` doens't matter. So if you want to call it, `assign-any`, you can pass that `attribute` by setting the property `name` as `name: assignAny`.

```js
var ang = angular.module('testApp', []);

ang.controller("controller1", controller1);
function controller1($scope) {
 $scope.controller1 = "Yay, im now part of the directive!!!";
}

ang.controller("controller2", controller2);
function controller2($scope) {
 $scope.controller2 = "controller2";
}

ang.controller("controller3", controller3);
function controller3($scope) {
 $scope.controller3 = "controller3";
}

ang.directive("testDirective", function() {
 return {
  restrict: 'AE',
  link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.controller = attrs.controller;
   console.log(scope);
  },
    template: "<h3>I return {{controller}}</h3>",
    controller: "@",
    name: "controller",
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp">
 <div ng-controller="controller1">
  {{controller1}}
 </div>
 <div ng-controller="controller2">
  {{controller2}}
 </div>
 <div ng-controller="controller3">
  {{controller3}}
  
  <test-directive data-controller="controller1"></test-directive>
 </div>
</div>
```

**I recommend to read this guide for a well explained tutorial on how to work with directives.**

### [Part one](https://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives/) and [Part two](https://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives-part-two/)